# Polar Chart in Higcharts 'negativeColor' not showing properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts, graphics

I have this polar chart which is populated at every 2 sec with new data by a function.

**What I want to achive:**

Display line/area series, based on 120 values, for every 3º (in the img 'Layer1, 'Column for Layer 2' and 'Total' recive the 120 values while 'Line' has only 8 values for every 45º).

Every time a value passes a Limit ( I use 'threshold: 500,'), that point must be turn in to 'red' ( I set it with 'negativeColor')

**My problem is:**

1. When the value is passed, it is not making the line red, just the point.
2. It has this problem with the line ..... because if my values are under the down half of the circle it is not showing any line at all, just the points (It doesn't matter if it is a line, or arearange type series). Like this:

[image: Graph img] .

**My code:**

```js
$(document).ready(
  function(datt) {
    chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        polar: true,
        zoomType: 'xy'
      },
      pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Polar distribution of layers thickness '
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.name + ' WT: ' + JSON.stringify(this.y / 35.5).slice(0, 6);
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        tickInterval: 45,
        gridLineColor: 'white',
        gridZIndex: 5,
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value + " º";
          }
        }
      },

      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        endOnTick: false,
        visible: false,
        maxPadding: 0,
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        arearange: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
          type: 'arearange',
          name: 'Layer 1',
          data: datt,
          color: '#19dde8',
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          lineWidth: 0.3,
          zIndex: 2
        },
        {
          type: 'arearange',
          name: 'Column for Layer 2',
          data: [
            [0, 419, 419],
            [45, 419, 419],
            [90, 419, 419],
            [135, 419, 419],
            [180, 419, 419],
            [225, 419, 419],
            [270, 419, 419],
            [315, 419, 419],
            [360, 419, 419]
          ],
          min: 400,
          color: '#e8d618',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          lineWidth: 0.3,
          threshold: 500,
          negativeColor: 'red'
        },
        {
          type: 'arearange',
          name: 'Total',
          data: [
            [0, 451, 451],
            [45, 451, 451],
            [90, 451, 451],
            [135, 451, 451],
            [180, 451, 451],
            [225, 451, 451],
            [270, 451, 451],
            [315, 451, 451],
            [360, 451, 451]
          ],
          lineWidth: 0.3,
          color: '#c8c5f9',
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          lineWidth: 0.3,
          zIndex: 7,
        },
        {
          type: 'line',
          name: 'Line',
          data: [
            [0, 619],
            [45, 639],
            [90, 649],
            [135, 659],
            [180, 669],
            [225, 639],
            [270, 629],
            [315, 699],
            [360, 609]
          ],
          lineWidth: 0.3,
          color: 'orange',
          threshold: 650,
          negativeColor: 'red',
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
          lineWidth: 0.3,
          zIndex: 7,
        }


      ]
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.2.0/es-modules/parts-more/Polar.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: I believe you have run into this open issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4936. You could try posting there with a minimalized example to point out that this is still an issue  and that `negativeColor` is not disabled for polar charts.

Comment: It looks like... Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately negativeColor property doesn't work properly in polar chart. As you can see it is reported and Highcharts core developer wrote: "As a short term solution, we must disable zones and negativeColor for polar charts, and specify that in the docs." https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4936.

The solution which I can suggest for you is to use multicolor series Highcharts module http://blacklabel.github.io/multicolor_series/. Check this demo with a similar chart to yours: https://jsfiddle.net/Bastss/1c8mbu9e//

```
load() {
    let chart = this;
    chart.series.forEach((series) => {
      if (series.userOptions.type != 'arearange') {
        series.data.forEach((point) => {
          if (point.y < 650) {
            console.log(point)
            point.update({
              color: "red",
              segmentColor: "red"
            })
          }
        })
      }
    })
    chart.reflow();
  }
}
```